# Swing desktop java application scroll

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I am new in swing java application and I am developing a small desktop application that creates jlabels at run time with every button click.

The problem is when the jlabels number is too much, I need to display a scroll in the jframe to make the user able to see all jlabels (jlabel created after the height of the jframe).

I tried jscroll pane and jscroll bar but with no use , please provide a complete example.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: "please provide a complete example" :) The fish wanted not the knowledge how to fish :) I this case it will take a lot longer to be a good programmer!

Comment: `"please provide a complete example"` -- Come on, that's not how it works here. Please show what you've done and let's work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me, please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to show specific problems, the only thing that springs to mind is you added you `JLabel` to the container and not the `JScrollPane`

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabelJScrollPaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {//size frame purposefully smaller
                        return new Dimension(100, 100);
                    }
                };
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("WWWWWWWWWoooooorrrrkkkk");
                JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(label);

                frame.add(jsp);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I see you say:

> (jlabel created after the height of the jframe).

So i take it the JFrame is visible? if so:

Here is an example which shows how to add `JLabel` to `JScrollPane` after 2 seconds of showing `JFrame`, most important is to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the containers instance after adding/removing/changing component sizes.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JLabelJScrollPaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(100, 100);
                    }
                };
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
                frame.add(jsp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

               Timer t= new Timer(2000, new AbstractAction() {//create timer to add JLabel to scrollPane after 2 seconds
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        final JLabel label = new JLabel("WWWWWWWWWoooooorrrrkkkk");
                        jsp.setViewportView(label);
                        //refelect changes
                        frame.revalidate();
                        frame.repaint();
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPADTE 2**

[image]

as per comment its the exact same thing with minor alterations:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JLabelJScrollPaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(100, 100);
                    }
                };
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));

                final JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(labelPanel);
                frame.add(jsp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Timer t = new Timer(2000, new AbstractAction() {//create timer to add JLabel to scrollPane after 2 seconds
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        final JLabel label = new JLabel("WWWWWWWWWoooooorrrrkkkk");
                        final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Try it");
                        final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Noooooo reealllly");
                        final JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Yes");
                        labelPanel.add(label);
                        labelPanel.add(label2);
                        labelPanel.add(label3);
                        labelPanel.add(label4);
                        labelPanel.revalidate();
                        labelPanel.repaint();
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need to add vertical scroll for more than one jLabel added in the runtime

Comment: @user1931998 see update 2. All you needed to do was alter the code........

Comment: Come on Dave, @user1931998 appears to want a **complete** example.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hehe, Ooh I see sorry, my mind reading skills are not up to scratch :P